# Errors when load selected raw data into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, cryptocurrency

I want to select three groups of json data and load them into a dataframe but i got the  errors "string indices must be integers". Can anyone kindly tell me what is the reason for it?

The code is as following and i have also attached the screenshot:

```
for currency in data:
if '/BTC' in currency['symbol']:
    change_daily=currency['percentage']
    name=currency["symbol"]
    price = currency['lastPrice']


df_binance.append({"NAME":name,"24h_change":change_daily,"PRICE":price})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `currency` is a key in `data` dictionary here:

```
for currency in data:
    if '/BTC' in data[currency]['symbol']:
        change_daily=data[currency]['percentage']
        name=data[currency]["symbol"]
        price = data[currency]['last']
        df_binance.append({"NAME":name,"24h_change":change_daily,"PRICE":price})
```

BTW you should define `df_binance` list before your loop. And better iterate with `for currency in data.keys()`

Update: Shorter load method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T.reset_index()[['symbol', 'percentage', 'last']]
df = df.loc[df.symbol.str.endswith("BTC")]
```

Comment: Thanks. Your reply perfectly answers my question. Just never thought of such a cleaner way of code. I have voted your answer but under 15 reputation